# Where do I find mechanism for paper flipping and refeeding in printers?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, robotics, machine-design

I've started out in engineering and can't seem to find the mechanism in printers that flip and refeed the paper back for printing. There are a few engineering YouTube videos that show machine mechanisms.

How do I get my hands on the engineering drawings of mechanisms I want (without actually having the physical machine for inspection)?

Comment: it's called a `duplex unit`

Comment: Some just change the position of a roller to change the paper path.

Comment: jsotola thanks for the name of the mechanism . but might i ask you a general source to find novel mechanisms and names of existing mechanisms?

Comment: @Dan.is.Asking enough info to target your research surely or do you really expect us to do it for you?

Comment: If it already exists find a printer that can do it, and buy it on ebay, then tear it apart. Patents are great but they don't always show the little details necessary to make it reliable (sometimes intentionally).

Comment: some inkjet printers have duplexing units... inkjet printer may be the simplest one to buy ... there are many available at second hand stores for cheap because they have clogged printheads

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SolarMike , No , Thank you for your input. i've gotten to work

Answer (score 1):

When you dont know how to do something and you know it being done by other companies, you take a look at the patents database.

Finding the name is another thing though. There is no inherent systematic way to name mechanical components. This is a very expensive issue. Something to solve this problem is worth billions.

In this paricular case you can just search patent database for things like flipping paper, two sided printing and you will get there soon enough.

Comment: Good Sir that's precisely what i'm exploring. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

You could visit a goodwill thrift store and look for a derelict printer with a *duplexer*, buy it for $20, and take it home for disassembly. The goodwill stores in my area are usually awash in 2nd- and 3rd-generation inkjet office printers, especially the big, clunky, feature-laden "all-in-one" models.

Comment: This is a good idea (though im sure you can get one for free too if your in the right place at right time), especially if you want to make just one device. While one is at it take a look at the paper lifting mechanism that ones has seen an insane amount of development.